# Dúvida com proteção dos dados em aplicativo

Tags: android, ios, segurança

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android e Iphone que guardará várias informações sensíveis dos meus clientes na base de dados do celular. Minha dúvida está sendo em qual a melhor forma de proteger esses dados:

- Sei que é possível criptografar a base de dados local do aplicativo, entretanto, se alguém de posse do celular logar como root irá conseguir obter a base de dados e através da descompilação do APK é possível extrair a chave que usei na criptografia e ter acesso aos dados.
- Minha segunda opção é utilizar a própria criptografia nativa do Android ou Iphone e criptografar todo o dispositivo.

Confesso que estou tendendo mais para a segunda opção, pois a primeira não me parece muito efetiva. Alguém tem uma ideia melhor ou conhece a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que dentre as duas opções, a segunda é a mais trivial. Contudo, eu sugeriria você criar um servidor web para armazenar esses dados, pois pessoas mal intencionadas não teriam acesso ao servidor e, consequentemente, não teriam acesso aos dados.

Comment: Infelizmente o aplicativo não pode depender de internet para funcionar, então não tenho como fugir de armazenar os dados localmente.

Comment: Então segue com a segunda opção mesmo. Será a ideal para o seu projeto.